# What are the triggers of the MD-80's takeoff configuration warnings?

Tags: takeoff, md-80, cockpit-alerts

I'm helping develop sounds for a MD80 simulation and I've noticed the MD has up to 5 alarms that fire when you advance the throttle and the aircraft is not properly prepared for takeoff:

- "Beep beep flaps": I assume when flaps < 11 degrees.
- "Beep beep slats": (???) Don't slats move along with flaps? Isn't it redundant?
- "Beep beep brakes": I assume you have parking brakes set.
- "Beep beep spoilers": I assume you have spoilers in other than stowed condition.
- "Beep beep stabilizer": (???) Stabilizer trim is off for takeoff? What is the correct setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 7 conditions, not 5. The two you are missing are:

- AUTO BRAKE
  This warning is when the auto brake system (ABS) has detected a fault, or the system is not activated.
- AUTO SPOILER
  This warning is when the spoilers are not armed when the ABS is set to takeoff.

**What flap setting triggers the warning?**

> Flaps lever position does not agree with selected position in computer window.

**Why slats and flaps have separate warnings?**

While the flaps/slats handle is the same, there could be a mechanical reason the slats failed to extend properly, or a circuit breaker is pulled. Also historically, the earlier DC-9 from which the MD-80 is developed, had a handle that could be physically [separated](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DC-9_Cockpit.jpg).

**What stabilizer setting triggers the warning?**

Same as flaps, when the position disagrees from the selected one in the computer (it varies from flight to flight based on the different conditions).

---

Source: MD-80 FCOM Section 6 Pages 76–77

Comment: Thanks a lot, that cleared everything up!